# Enum pointing to gameobjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, gameobject

So, I have this crazy idea to have enums pointing to gameobjects.

Here's what I want to do:

```
/* These enums would hold gameobjects instead of ints */
enum exampleEnum{
    AddPanel,
    ListPanel
}

public class GUIManager : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start()
    {
        EnablePanel(exampleEnum.AddPanel);
    }

    void EnablePanel(GameObject panel)
    {
        panel.setActive(true);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make this work? Or a workaround?

This might be possible with something other than an enum but I don't know of it if there is and I'm looking through the web for a such a solution.

Comment: Use a switch case.

Comment: I don't want a massive switch holding a bunch of cases unfortunately.

Comment: I want this to work and be clean even if I had 500 panels to activate.

Comment: From experience, you won't gain much by doing this and the resulting code will probably be fragile.

Comment: @Amy So it is possible? And how would it be fragile? For what I plan to do, this idea seems like the most flexible way to do it.

Comment: This and the given answer sound like massive overhead while you'd be better off just setting the value for each panel on the panels themselves. You have a manager to control the states of all items via an array...hold on so if you remove a UI item, how do you reset it all? How is it making sure item 5 is panel 5 and if you removed 4 (or another coder did)....well you get it....or actually you don't because this is not intuitive. Set it on the panel instead of the manager, and make the on/off happen in their own start. The manager will propagate the change of state to all panels.

Comment: I just threw in as little information as needed to convey an answer out of it. That code snip isn't the actual use of my question. I simply figured that an answer wouldn't require every piece I had.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would satisfy your requirement, works for any amount of enum values or panels.

```
// Add this to each of your panels, the enum field can be integrated into your other behaviours as well
public class EnumPanel : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // configurable from the Editor, the unity way.
    public ExampleEnum Type;
}

// Assign all your panles in the editor (or use FindObjectsByType<EnumPanel> in Start())
public class GUIManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // configurable from the Editor, the unity way.
    public EnumPanel[] Panels;

    void Start()
    {
        // Optionally find it at runtime, if assigning it via the editor is too much maintenance.
        // Panels = FindObjectsByType<EnumPanel>();
        EnablePanel(ExampleEnum.AddPanel);
    }

    void EnablePanel(ExampleEnum panelType)
    {
        foreach(var panel in Panels)
        {
            if(panel.Type == panelType)
                EnablePanel(panel.gameObject);
        }
    }

    void EnablePanel(GameObject panel)
    {
        panel.setActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alox was this what you were looking for? If so, please mark the answer so it is removed from the unanswered section.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a meeting, it looks like what I'm looking for, I'll try it out to be sure but simply by looking at the code it looks like a great answer.

Comment: Just a little side note, do not use a `foreach` to iterate the Panels if you use anything other than an array (a list for example), use a `for` it saves on garbage collection (40 bytes for the IEnumerator) thus giving you a slightly higher FPS, and only costs 1 extra line of code. I did not add it in my code example above for clarity's sake.

Comment: Only a solution to the OP's answer is required, which was how to bind Enums to Objects, not the technicalities behind the scope of a manager. We do not know the technical specifications of his project so how can you judge whether or not logic should be executed in his manager, please do not add off-topic discussion to answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the answer from: @Paradox Forge was wrong but maybe this will help you.

> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

I don't have a lot of time to explain the dictionary class but this is how you can use it.
This will cost some performance but has really nice readability

```cs
    public class GUIManager : MonoBehaviour {
        public enum exampleEnum{
            AddPanel,
            ListPanel
        }

        //For readability you can also add "using System.Collections.Generic;" on the top of your script
        private System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<exampleEnum,GameObject> exampleDictionary = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<exampleEnum, GameObject>();

        private GameObject SomeGameObject;
        private GameObject SomeOtherGameObject;

        void Start()
        {
            //You have to add all the enums and objects you want to use inside your GUIManager.
            exampleDictionary.Add (exampleEnum.AddPanel, SomeGameObject); //Add panel will be linked to SomeGameObject
            exampleDictionary.Add (exampleEnum.ListPanel, SomeOtherGameObject); //List Panel will be linked to SomeOtherGameObject

            EnablePanel(exampleEnum.AddPanel);
        }

        void EnablePanel(exampleEnum examplePanel)
        {
            if (!exampleDictionary.ContainsKey (examplePanel)) //If the given panel does not exist inside the dictionary
                return; //Leave the method

            GameObject panelToEnable = exampleDictionary [examplePanel]; //Will return the GameObject linked to given panel
            panelToEnable.SetActive(true); //Enable the gameobject
        }
    }
```

If you want to know more about the Dictionary class go to: [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I only heard of dictionaries but I wasn't sure how to use them, this is also a possible answer for my question but I unfortunately can't have two answers.